# Datetimepicker is not a function in Vue js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I  have an issue with the boostrap datetimepicker, I created a vue component for so it can be reusable since I need to used it more that once, seems like everything is working fine when I run the project but if I reload the page I get the error datetimepicker is not a function.
The weird thing is that I have 2 vue components one for my driver form and the other of my excluded driver form. Driver form is the first one to load and then the ED form, when I reload the page I only get the error on the driver component but I can always use the datetimepicker on the Excluded driver form without problem.

This is the datetimepicker component:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" :id="templateid" />

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dateTimePicker = Vue.component('date-picker', {
        template: '#date-picker-input',
        props: ['dateFormat', 'datePicker', 'templateId','field'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                dated: this.datePicker,
                templateid: this.templateId
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            var self = this;
            $('#' + self.templateid).val(self.dated);

            $(this.$el).datetimepicker({
                format: this.dateFormat
            }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
                $('#' + self.templateid).val();
                self.dated = $('#' + self.templateid).val();
                //console.log(self.dated);
                self.$emit('update-date', self.dated, self.field);
            });
        }

    });

</script>

<date-picker :date-format="dateFormat" 
                         :date-picker="excludedDriver.DateOfBirth"
                         v-on:update-date="updateDate"
                         :field="'DateOfBirth'"
                         :template-id="getFormFieldId(excludedDriver.DriverId, 'DateOfBirth')"></date-picker>
```

That is how I call it (its basically the same form for excluded drivers and drivers)
Please help = C

Comment: Could show how did you installed or imported bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Comment: I used the nuget package on Visual Studio. I'm working with MVC, each my partial view is a vue component.